# If Session get login in javascript (laravel 5.6)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I got a little problem with Javascript in laravel 5.6.

I have a wizard setup here, and there are 3 steps.

- Step 1. login or register
- Step 2. another div (hidden)
- Step 3. another div (hidden)

If I still don't have a login session (here I use the session for the login)
then I want to go directly to step 2 (hidden div 1 and 2)

And my statement is how do I get login session logic on javascript?

This is the markup for the view:

```
       <div class="container">
          <div class="stepwizard1">
              <div class="stepwizard-row1 setup-panel">
                  <div class="stepwizard-step1">
                      <a id="a-step1" href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle"></a>Step 1</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="stepwizard-step1">
                      <a id="a-step2" href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle disabled"></a>
                      <p>Step 2</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="stepwizard-step1">
                      <a id="a-step3" href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle disabled"></a>
                      <p>Step 3</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

        <div class="tab-panel setup-content" id="step-1">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <section class="content">
                <div class="login">
                  <h2>masuk</h2>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible alert-login" style="display:none;"></div>
                  <form id="form-login">
                  <div id="label_email">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div id="label_password">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password"/>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="button nextBtn">Masuk</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>

  <div class="tab-panel setup-content " id="step-2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <section class="content">
            <div class="login">
            <h2>Alamat</h2>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible alert-login" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div id="label_email">
                <input type="text" placeholder="alamat" name="alamat" id="alamat"/>
            </div>
            <div id="label_password">
                <input type="text" placeholder="kodepos" name="kodepos" id="kodepos"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="button nextBtn">Next</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

btw, here I use ajax for the login form...

Thanks in advance, and I'm sorry if it's still wrong because I am still relatively new in the world of programs and my bad...very bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are using a laravel then you can take advantage of blade templating engine

```
@auth
// The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
// The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

Then you could set some classes inside those code blocks and style them. Your steps will be easier to implement.

If, however, you really want to use Ajax to check if user is authenticated, You could make a function in your controller to return a user status like

```
public function isLogged() {
  if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
  }
}
```

And set up a root path like 
`Route::post( '/isUserLogged', 'UserController@isLogged' );`

Oh, and one more thing, if you are using steps that could get ugly JS code pretty fast. I would suggest to use a Vuejs framework which has already built in the Laravel.

Good luck :)

Comment: I don't know that laravel has vue.js !! thank you very much sir, you just saved my time..

Comment: Glad to help you.